# Как сверстать кнопку с эффектами наведения и нажатия?

Tags: css

Как можно сверстать кнопку с эффектами наведения и нажатия?
На картинке первое изображение по умолчанию, второе при наведении, третье при нажатии.

[image]

Проблема в следующем. Во-первых, изображение с прозрачным фоном, и если вставлять его
фоном кнопки, то прозрачный фон заменяется белым фоном. Также непонятно, как сделать
эффекты наведения и нажатия на кнопке.

Если делать дивом, то проблема в том, что картинка будет загружаться при наведении,
то есть пользователь не сразу видит, что картинка поменялась при наведении.

Эта кнопка используется для отправки формы. Как можно её лучше реализовать?
Ещё можно ли, чтобы текст на кнопке был текстом, а не картинкой?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: нажатие - css :active , наведение :hover,  текст - text-shadow, фон - background-image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых сохраняйте картинку не в jpg, а в png c прозрачностью, тогда никакого белого фона не будет. 
Во-вторых сохраните её именно в таком вариант, в котором вы нам показали ( так называемый sprite ).

Сделайте ссылку блочной и задайте ей ширину и высоту одной из трёх картинки вашего спрайта. Укажите background: url(../sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; и по умолчанию будет выводится первая картинка. Чтобы менять картинки при наведении и нажатии, достаточно в стилях прописать что-то типа:

```
.button {
    display: block; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(../sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px; }

.button:hover {
    background-position: 0 -32px; /* координаты нашей второй картинки*/
 }

.button:active {
    background-position: 0 -64px; /* координаты нашей второй картинки*/
}
```

Как видите текст я сделал белым и выровнял по центру по ширине и высоте. Для этого наши картинки нужно сохранить без текста.

P.s. Т.к. фоны для кнопок у нас одной картинкой, то она сразу загрузится и при манипуляциях с кнопкой (:hover, :active ) фона будут меняться мгновенно.

Comment: Картинка в формате PNG. И при вставке в кнопку (которая инпут тайп=сабмит) фон из прозрачного превращается в белый.

Comment: Про спрайты спасибо. Я так понял, эти стили к диву применимы? Или к кнопке тоже можно?

Comment: К кнопке тоже применимо, спасибо.